# Изменении цвета иконок в StatusBar

Tags: java, android, android-style

Погуглив на эту тему не смог найти инфы как изменить цвет текста и иконок в StatusBar, меня интересует возможно ли это?

Comment: Думается, максимум что можно изменить это цвет самого statusbar-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно ответам к этому [вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30075827/3212712) гугл хочет, чтобы иконки сии всегда были белые и, засим, не даёт способов это поменять и даже сам пресекает все попытки это сделать.

Единственное найденное [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33316669/3212712) - замена цвета иконок на серый на андроид > 6

В стилях (`values-v23/styles.xml`):

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

И в коде:

```
View yourView = findViewById(R.id.your_view);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (yourView != null) {
        yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо за информацию!